# How do i access the nodes for text in blender?

Tags: text, blender, modeling

I was looking for a way to animate text in blender, i found a way but the way it was done used nodes involving the text object, how can i access this set of nodes?
[image: top picture is the nodes]

here is my blender screen: (don't pay attention to what i'm doing)[image: my screen]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first image you found shows nodes from the [Animation Nodes](https://github.com/JacquesLucke/animation_nodes) addon. Note that current versions contain compiled code, if the pre-built releases listed don't match your system you will need to [build it yourself](https://animation-nodes-manual.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev_guide/index.html).

You may want to try a simpler solution first, the [Animated Text addon](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/BAC/browse/master/animation_text_types.py) offers several text animation options.